# Using Markov property on brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

let $P_x$ a probability measure under which $(B_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is a brownian motion startetd at $x>0$ and let $\tau_0 := \inf\lbrace B_t = 0\rbrace$ the first hitting time of $0$. For positive $t$, $y$ and $\varepsilon$, I want to show:

$$P_x(B_t \in (y,y+\varepsilon),\tau_0< t) = P_x(B_t \in (-y-\varepsilon,-y))$$

I want to use the strong Markov property at the stopping time $\tau_0$. Do I have to integrate with respect to $P_x(\tau_0 \in ds)$?

EDIT: We can safely write $$P_x(B_t \in (y,y+\varepsilon),\tau_0< t) = E_x[1_{\lbrace\tau_0 < t\rbrace} E_x[1_{\lbrace B_t\in (y,y+\varepsilon) \rbrace}|\mathcal{F}_{\tau_0}]].$$ From my understanding this equals $$\int\limits_{\Omega} 1_{\lbrace\tau_0(\omega) < t\rbrace} \left(E_x[1_{\lbrace B_t\in (y,y+\varepsilon) \rbrace}|\mathcal{F}_{\tau_0}]\right)(\omega)P_x(d\omega).$$

Now, is it true, that for any $\omega$ with $\tau_0(\omega) < t$ we can apply the strong Markov property so that $$ \left(E_x[1_{\lbrace B_t\in (y,y+\varepsilon) \rbrace}|\mathcal{F}_{\tau_0}]\right)(\omega) = E_{B_{\tau_0(\omega)}} [1_{\lbrace B_t-\tau_0(\omega)\in (y,y+\varepsilon) \rbrace}] $$ a.s. ?

Is the random variable $\left(E_x[1_{\lbrace B_t\in (y,y+\varepsilon) \rbrace}|\mathcal{F}_{\tau_0}]\right)(\omega)$ a.s. the same as $\left(E_x[1_{\lbrace B_t\in (y,y+\varepsilon) \rbrace}|\mathcal{F}_{\tau_0(\omega)}]\right)(\omega)$ ?

Comment: You forgot to mention that you assume that $$x>0$$ Then the result is a direct consequence of the reflection principle at time $\tau_0$. More in details, consider $$W_t=B_t\mathbf 1_{t<\tau_0}-B_t\mathbf 1_{t>\tau_0}$$ then $W$ is a Brownian motion starting at $x$ and, for every $C\subseteq(0,+\infty)$, $$[B_t\in C,\tau_0<t]=[W_t\in-C]$$ hence your result follows.

Comment: @Did Thanks and yes, I assume $x>0$ and forgot to mention. In your answer, is $C\in \mathcal{B}((0,\infty))$ or truly $C\subseteq (0,\infty)$ ? I think I understand your answer which solves the original problem, but have general interest in the questions posed in the edit

Comment: Of course C should be Borel.